# Dice Roll in C# with Array

Tags: c#

I'm a newbie in C# right now. This is something I'm working on.

I'm trying to create a Dice Roll Game where when you press & hold the button, it will keep randomizing the dice continuously and stop when you release the button and also show the result of the dice every time you release the button. As you can see in the code, I tried using indexes in the array plus one to make up the result. But somehow the result is always just plus 3 every time I release the button and I don't know why.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Roll_Dice
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        // Variable Declaration
        int interval, result, indexDicepath01, indexDicepath02, indexDicepath03;
        string Path01, Path02, Path03;
        Random picture01 = new Random(), picture02 = new Random(), picture03 = new Random();
        
        // Create Array
        string[] Dicepath = {"A:\\Au Personal Folder\\Learning\\ปี 1 เทอม 1\\DIT101\\Week 21-9-2021\\Assignment\\Dice paths\\1.png",
            "A:\\Au Personal Folder\\Learning\\ปี 1 เทอม 1\\DIT101\\Week 21-9-2021\\Assignment\\Dice paths\\2.png",
        "A:\\Au Personal Folder\\Learning\\ปี 1 เทอม 1\\DIT101\\Week 21-9-2021\\Assignment\\Dice paths\\3.png",
        "A:\\Au Personal Folder\\Learning\\ปี 1 เทอม 1\\DIT101\\Week 21-9-2021\\Assignment\\Dice paths\\4.png",
        "A:\\Au Personal Folder\\Learning\\ปี 1 เทอม 1\\DIT101\\Week 21-9-2021\\Assignment\\Dice paths\\5.png",
        "A:\\Au Personal Folder\\Learning\\ปี 1 เทอม 1\\DIT101\\Week 21-9-2021\\Assignment\\Dice paths\\6.png"};
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            speed_text.Text = "1";
        }

        private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Random_Pic01(); Random_Pic02(); Random_Pic03();
            pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(Path01); pictureBox2.Image = Image.FromFile(Path02); pictureBox3.Image = Image.FromFile(Path03);
        }
        private void Random_Pic01()
        {
            int indexDicepath01 = picture01.Next(Dicepath.Length);
            Path01 = Dicepath[indexDicepath01];
        }
        private void Random_Pic02()
        {
            int indexDicepath2 = picture02.Next(Dicepath.Length);
            Path02 = Dicepath[indexDicepath2];
        }
        private void Random_Pic03()
        {
            int indexDicepath3 = picture03.Next(Dicepath.Length);
            Path03 = Dicepath[indexDicepath3];
        }

        private void button1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            int interval = Convert.ToInt32(speed_text.Text);
            Timer.Interval = interval*1000;
            Timer.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void button1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Timer.Enabled = false;
            indexDicepath01+=1;indexDicepath02+=1;indexDicepath03+=1;
            result = indexDicepath01 + indexDicepath02 + indexDicepath03;
            textBox2.Text = result.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside methods `Random_Pic01`, `Random_Pic02` and `Random_Pic03`, we **don't** have to *re-declare* a local variable for the variables `indexDicepath1`, `indexDicepath2` and `indexDicepath3` correspondingly. We just have to assign the corresponding values:

```
indexDicepath01 = picture01.Next(Dicepath.Length);
indexDicepath02 = picture02.Next(Dicepath.Length);
indexDicepath03 = picture03.Next(Dicepath.Length);
```

The reason it is always 3, is the fact that all variables: `indexDicepath01`, `indexDicepath02` and `indexDicepath03` would have the value of zero, when the following statements are going to be executed:

```
indexDicepath01+=1;indexDicepath02+=1;indexDicepath03+=1;
```

They would have the value of zero. First, because since they are not initialized anywhere explicitly, they are assigned their default value (0 for type `int`). Second, because they are not updated until the event handler `button1_MouseUp` is called.

Hence, they will become all 1 and consequently their sum, `result`, would be *always* 3.

Comment: @NOTMOE You are very welcome. Didn't you try the suggestion ? Isn't clear what's the issue ? In any case, please let me know, in order I revise correspondingly my answer. Thanks !!

Comment: I have tried your suggestion. It's turn out the result still returns only 3. So I tried to move the line [ indexDicepath01+=1;indexDicepath02+=1;indexDicepath03+=1; ] to the Timer_Tick method and it's work. But your explanation was really helpful for understanding Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Right now I encounter the problem "random always the same" instead.